# Is there a open source captive portal with category based content filtering available?

Tags: content-filter, captive-portal

I was thinking about deploying pfSense but then I realized there isn't a solid content filtering option with it. I know there are some squid addons but they seem cumbersome and not fully matured. Being able to filter based on categories is a big plus. Reading around it seems that untangle would be my best bet but the lite (free) version does not have AD integration. Not having it is not a deal breaking but again it would be nice. The content filter would be placed between the firewall and a router so thous features would not be needed.

I have a dedicated server I can run the software on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Firewall distributions include squidGuard as content-filtering solution.
An alternative approach could be some dns-side content-filtering, like OpenDNS.

Answer (score 0):

[Zeroshell](http://www.zeroshell.net/eng/) is a Linux distribution for servers and embedded devices aimed at providing the main network services a LAN requires.
There is integrated Proxy and AD integration.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I really just need content filtering. Like I said I have a firewall and router in front of and behind this device.